# Scalatest and Spark giving "java.io.NotSerializableException: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, rdd, scalatest

I’m testing a Spark Streaming application with the help of "**com.holdenkarau.spark-testing-base**" and **scalatest**.

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.scalatest.{ BeforeAndAfter, FunSuite }

class Test extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with StreamingSuiteBase {

  var delim: String = ","

  before {
    System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")
   }

  test(“This Fails“) {

    val source = scala.io.Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource(“/some_logs.csv"))
    val input = source.getLines.toList

    val rowRDDOut = Calculator.do(sc.parallelize(input))   //Returns DataFrame

    val report: RDD[String] = rowRDDOut.map(row => new String(row.getAs[String](0) + delim + row.getAs[String](1))

    source.close
  }
}
```

I get Serialization exception for field '***delim***':

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
[info]   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper
[info] Serialization stack:
[info]  - object not serializable (class: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper, value: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper@78b339fa)
[info]  - field (class: org.scalatest.FunSuite, name: assertionsHelper, type: class org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper)
```

If I replace 'delim' by String value in place, it works fine.

```
val report: RDD[String] = rowRDDOut.map(row => new String(row.getAs[String](0) + “,” + row.getAs[String](1))
```

What’s the difference between first and second version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is not the type of `delim` (String) it's `delim` itself.

Try not to define variables outside your `test()` methods. If you define `delm` inside your `test` it should work.

```
test(“This Fails“) {
   val delim = ","
   ...
}
```

Now, you may ask why? Well, when you reference `delim` from the outer scope, Scala will try to bring together the enclosing object `class Test`. This object contains a reference to `org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper` that it's not Serializable (see your stacktrace).

Comment: Whoa Sir! Couldn't even think that! Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Though I was getting the same error, I never thought my test class was in closure

Comment: had similar issue with the scala check generator, for some reason its must be declared within a test for things to work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, and the error persisted even after I moved all my code inside the test as mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081112/184).

Finally, found out that I was using wrong syntax in the code (which the compiler did not catch). In my case it was something like:

```
// Wrong
df.filter(x => x.id === y)

// Right
df.filter(x => x.id == y)
```